# Eliminar filas dinamicamente de Tabla HTML con AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un código el cual debe de ingresar o eliminar la última fila según lo necesitemos de una tabla HTML con AJAX

Estos son mis botones:

```
<button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button" id="insert-more"> Agregar Artículo</button>              
<button class="btn btn-success removebutton" type="button" id="delete-more"> Eliminar Último artículo</button>
```

Y este el código AJAX:

```
 $("#insert-more").click(function () {
 $("#mytable").each(function () {
     var tds = '<tr>';
     jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
         tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
     });
     tds += '</tr>';
     if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
         $('tbody', this).append(tds);
     } else {
         $(this).append(tds);
     }
 });
});


$("#delete-more").click(function () {
 $("#mytable").each(function () {
          var tds = '<tr>';
     jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
         tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
     });
     tds += '</tr>';
     if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
         $('tbody', this).remove(tds);
     } else {
         $(this).remove(tds);
     }
 });
 });
```

El botón de agregar filas funciona perfectamente el que no funciona es el de eliminarlas, pensaba que habia entendido el `.remove` de Ajax pero veo que no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola prueba reemplazando la función por:

```
$("#delete-more").click(function () {
    $('#mytable tr:last-child').remove();
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo completo aunque también cambie el agregar columna..

```js
var i = 1;
 
function agregarFila() {
  $("#dataTable").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>"+ i*10 +"</td></tr>");
  i += 1;
}

function quitarFila() {
   $('#dataTable tr:last-child').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="agregarFila()">agregar</button>
<button type="button" onclick="quitarFila()">quitar</button>
<table id="dataTable">
</table>
```

Comment: De esta manera deja de funcionar el ingresar linea y ninguno funciona

Comment: Que raro lo probé y funciona correctamente, te deje un ejemplo completo para que veas

Comment: Vale perfecto, ya lo voy pillando, ahora debo modificar tu `function agregarFila() {
  $("#dataTable").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>"+ i*10 +"</td></tr>");
  i += 1;
}` por una que ingrese el `tr + td`